# Controllers devem ter uma única responsabilidade?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Assim como as classes e objetos de uma aplicação, meus *controllers* devem ter uma única responsabilidade?

#### Exemplo.

Tenho meu *controller* `Cliente`, que tem todas as relações com meu *model* `Cliente`.

Tenho também o *model* `Contato`.

Seria certo eu ter minhas *actions* `ContatoPorCliente`, `ExcluirContatoCliente`, etc. dentro do meu *controller* `Cliente`? Essas *actions* são chamadas na *view* `Cliente`.

Minha dúvida é por que as vezes temos telas que tem várias Abas(Tab) em um formulário.
Cliente que tem Contato, Dados Financeiro, etc...

Comment: Sim, isso sim, mas e quando há referencia de Contato com Cliente, aonde tu faz suas actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não vejo problema em fazer isso, desde que os contatos referidos tenham alguma relação com o cliente, deixando explícito que são contatos de um cliente.

Caso existam outros caminhos, sem ser pela View de cliente, de manipular contatos, aí sim, eu acho que a separação se torna mais necessária.

Sabe, padrões de organização de código existem para ajudar a mover o ponto no projeto em que o código é feito... a separação de responsabilidades prevê uma necessidade que normalmente vem a tona durante a fase de manutenção (e que é um pesadelo): o acoplamento, então é melhor fazer um código com baixo grau de acoplamento desde o início.

Se contato for algo que existe somente como algo que faz parte do cliente, então o acoplamento não será alto de qualquer forma... caso contrário é melhor separar desde já.

Comment: Minha dúvida é por que as vezes temos telas que tem várias Abas(Tab) em um formulário. No exemplo que citei, contato pode estar por tudo, Cliente,Prestador, entre outras

Comment: No caso, acho que deve haver uma regra única. Se em cada aba podem haver itens que são agregados de cliente, e em outra existem itens que se relacionam com várias outras partes do sistema, aí eu prefiro já separar tudo. Um sistema com menos regras, e portanto mais simples, tem mais chances de sobreviver.